# Do I HAVE to choose a subrace? And how do I add ability scores if I do?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, ability-scores

Let's say I made a dwarf character. In the dwarf traits I should add +2 constitution. If I pick Hill Dwarf as my subrace do I get both +2 constitution AND +1 Wisdom from hill dwarf trait?

Answer (score 28):

**You have to choose one.**

*Subrace* is a trait from the dwarf race, with the following description (PHB 20):

> **Subrace**. Two main subraces of dwarves populate the worlds of D&D: hill dwarves and mountain dwarves. *Choose one of these subraces*.

And yes, you get both bonuses (so +2 Constitution and +1 Wisdom).

(Note that there is a third official subrace available in the [Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide), the gray dwarves, also known as the duergar (SCAG 104). This subrace can cast some spells innately, but suffers from sunlight, like the other Underdark races.)